# Error in concatenation expression

Tags: sql-server-2005

Just a beginner, but can't figure out the reason for my error.  Trying to create the 'email' field with the following query:

```
SET Students.Email = FirstName + "." + LastName + "@mycollege.edu"
```

but get the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: I understand your question is about *concatenation*. I've changed your question's title accordingly. If I'm mistaken, please feel free to roll it back.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
UPDATE Students SET Email = FirstName + '.' + LastName + '@mycollege.edu'
```

But I'd suggest you read up on SQL Server and how to use SQL - this is an extremely basic question and I'm sure [Google](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=sql%20update%20statement%20example&aq=1sx&aqi=g-s1g-sx4&aql=f&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=a316b5cdb3fe9040&pf=p&pdl=300) or [Bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=sql%20update%20statement%20example&go=&form=QBLH&qs=n&sk=&sc=1-28) have some answers for you.

Comment: *sigh*  I knew it would be something quite simple.  Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Also it's not a "join" so I'm not sure why that's in your question title - is there more to it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to [`UPDATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) the table:

```
UPDATE Students
SET Email = FirstName + "." + LastName + "@mycollege.edu"
```